# Show that if $p > 1$ and $p|(p-1)! +1$, then $p$ is prime.

Tags: number-theory

I have covered prime numbers and division, this is what i have so far.

if $ p | (p-1)! +1$ then $(p-1)! +1 = ap$ for some $a$.

so $(p-1)(p-2)! +1 = ap$.

I'm aware from googling that this is related to Wilson's theorem, but the proof involves congruences, which i have not covered yet.

Comment: The opposite way is covered by Wilson´s theorem that (p-1)!=-1 (mod p) for p prime.

Comment: also, (n-1)! with n non-prime will contain two factors a,b < (n-1) such that  ab = n = 0 (mod n) and therefore not -1.

Comment: Wilson's theorem covers "if and only if". So OP's clain follows from it.

Comment: @MikaelJensen  ${}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ If $\,p\,$ is composite then it has a proper factor $\,d,\,$ i.e. $\,d\mid p\,$ and  $\, 1 < d < p.\,$ Then

$\qquad\! \color{#c00}d < p\ \Rightarrow\, (p\!-\!1)! = (p\!-\!1)(p\!-\!2)\cdots \color{#c00}d \cdots 2\cdot 1\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}d\mid \color{#c00}{(p\!-\!1)!}$

Furthermore  $\,\ \color{}d\mid p\mid \color{#0a0}{1\!+(p\!-\!1)!}\,$ therefore $\,d\mid \color{#0a0}{1\!+\!(p\!-\!1)!} - \color{#c00}{(p\!-\!1)!}\ $ i.e. $\,d\mid 1,\,$ contradiction.

**Remark** $\ $ Above we used the property  $\,d\mid \color{#0a0}a,\color{#c00}b\,\Rightarrow\,d\mid\color{#0a0}a-\color{#c00}b.\,$ Indeed then $\,a=d a_1\,$ and $\,b = db_1\,$ therefore $\,a-b = da_1 - d b_1 = d(a_1 - b_1)\,$ is divisible $\,d.\ $  Also we used the *transitivity* of divisibility, i.e. $\,d\mid p\mid n\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid n.\,$ Indeed if $\, p = dp_1\,$ then $\, n = p n_1 = (d p_1) n_1 = d(p_1 n_1)\,$ is divisible by $\,d.$